# Picking an Object randomly based on another Object and probability?

Tags: c++, random, probability-density

I have a base class called bait that has children classes some bait names, suppose bait1,bait2...etc and another fishes classes fish1,fish2,...etc

I want the user to pick a bait and for each bait there is a probability that he catches a certain fish eg. if he chose bait1, there's a probability 40% he catches fish1 and a probability 30% he catches fish2 and a probability 25% he catches fish3 and a probability 5% he catches fish4, and if he chooses bait2 same as example but with different probabilities, any idea how to implement this ?

sorry I fixed the problem with the previous example

Comment: Are the probabilities related to each other in *any* way? E.g. each fish has a probability and each bait has a multiplier for this probability? Otherwise if you have F fishes and B baits, you have F*B different probabilities.

Comment: [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) should be helpful, although you need to clarify the problem a little more.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour you shoul put that down as an answer

Comment: @nurettin OP clarified, so I added an answer

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour +1 for discrete_distribution

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for bait 1 using [std::discrete_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution), you can see a live example [here](http://rextester.com/ZRJSFF97038):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::discrete_distribution<> bait1({40,30,25,5});
    std::map<int, int> m;
    for(int n=0; n<10000; ++n) {
        ++m[bait1(gen)];
    }
    for(auto p : m) {
        std::cout << "fish " <<  (p.first+1) << " generated " << p.second << " times\n";
    }
}
```

sample output:

```
fish 1 generated 3964 times
fish 2 generated 2981 times
fish 3 generated 2544 times
fish 4 generated 511 times
```

modifying this for bait 2 etc... should be straight forward